# How to save an HTML5 canvas element as an image?

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 to develop a native mobile app.

I have one canvas element in the app which I need to save as an image file in the local storage of mobile device. The code is given below:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="sketch">
    <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
</div>
<input type="button" name="saveCanvas" value="Save" onclick="saveCanvas()">

    <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Java Script:**

```
function saveCanvas() {

 var canvas = document.getElementById("paint");        
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");                   

 var myimage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
 window.location.href=myimage; 

}
```

I need a pop up window to allow user to save the image in local storage. Now the problem is, when I test the app in Worklight Mobile Browser Simulator, a pop up window opens to save the image but it does not work when I test it in Android Virtual Device or in my device.

Please help me to know how can I save my canvas as an image in local storage of the device.

Answer (score 2):

Had this application been a web app which is not based on Worklight/Cordova, you could have used your code or [this HTML5 Canvas example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/) and it will indeed work...

However, when in the context of a Cordova app (or Worklight app), the Cordova WebView does not have "download permission". So you are required to use the [Cordova File or FileTransfer API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) to save the converted image to the local storage.

You can also try to use this Cordova plug-in: [Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin)

- Because you are using Worklight 6.0, which uses Cordova 2.6, you will need to use v0.2 of the plug-in. This version is missing the Java implementation, so you'll need to copy it over from v0.4 and modify it somewhat I believe...
- If you choose to upgrade to Worklight 6.1, which uses Cordova 3.1, you can use v0.5 of the plug-in that does not require anything other than what is written in the plug-in guidelines.

You can of course choose to write one of your own or fork the above...

Comment: Hi, author of the Canvas2ImagePlugin here... sadly, the Android implementation of the plugin was a contribution by another developer and it was done after the plugin had been converted to Cordova 3.x compatibility. I am not sure what it would take to backport the Android implementation to the v0.2.0 version of the plugin... I am going to try to have a look, but I don't know if I'll have time.